# Setting column in Google Sheets API (with Python) to be number-formatted

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to format a column of numbers in Google Sheets using the API (Sheets API v.4 and Python 3.6.1, specifically). A portion of my non-functional code is below. I know it's executing, as the background color of the column gets set, but the numbers still show as text, not numbers.

Put another way, I'm trying to get the equivalent of clicking on a column header (A, B, C, or whatever) then choosing the Format -> Number -> Number menu item in the GUI.

```
def sheets_batch_update(SHEET_ID,data):
    print ( ("Sheets: Batch update"))
    service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=SHEET_ID,body=data).execute() #,valueInputOption='RAW'

data={
  "requests": [
    {
      "repeatCell": {
        "range": {
          "sheetId": all_sheets['Users'],
          "startColumnIndex": 19,
          "endColumnIndex": 20
        },
        "cell": {
          "userEnteredFormat": {
            "numberFormat": {
                "type": "NUMBER",
                "pattern": "#,##0",
            },
            "backgroundColor": {
              "red": 0.0,
              "green": 0.4,
              "blue": 0.4
            },
          }
        },
        "fields": "userEnteredFormat(numberFormat,backgroundColor)"
      }
    },   
  ]
}
sheets_batch_update(SHEET_ID, data)
```

Comment: If you are converting a pre-valued cell text from `one` to `1`, I think that the userEnteredFormat:numberFormat() will not convert that. A workaround would be creating your own library for converting text to numbers. Another thing you can do is create a [Conditional Formatting](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/conditional-formatting) to check if the entered value for the cell is a number or a text a provide a validator for the cell. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Rebot -- he columns actually contain "1" "2" etc. not "one" "two" and so on. But Google seems to be seeing the "1" "2" etc as text, not numbers, even if they're an int in python, hence my desire to format them as numbers.

Comment: Would formatting it via an internal Google Script that's called on sheet update be a solution or do you only want to do it via Python?

Comment: Thanks @TomWoodward -- I could do it via a Google Apps Script, and that's an interesting idea, but I'd rather do it via Python if at all possible. What I'm doing is automated reporting pushing its results into a sheet, where a new sheet is created each day when the reporting script runs via cron, so it would be a lot easier if it could all be 100% automated. I also don't understand why what I'm doing _isn't_ working: everything I read indicates that it should work....

Comment: Yep. I agree with you and FWIW everything I see you doing matched up with the documentation. It sure does look like it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely that your data is currently stored as strings and therefore not affected by the number format.

```
"userEnteredValue": {
  "stringValue": "1000"
},
"formattedValue": "1000",
"userEnteredFormat": {
  "numberFormat": {
    "type": "NUMBER",
    "pattern": "#,##0"
  }
},
```

When you set a number format via the UI (**Format > Number > ...**) it's actually doing two things at once:

1. Setting the number format.
2. Converting string values to number values, if possible.

Your API call is only doing #1, so any cells that are currently set with a string value will remain a string value and will therefore be unaffected by the number format. One solution would be to go through the affected values and move the `stringValue` to a `numberValue` if the cell contains a number.

Comment: Thanks @Eric! That did the trick.  I actually ended up fixing it in two ways--see the next response for the details.

Comment: Thanks, man! I've spent an hour looking at why the format is not applied.

Answer (score 1):

To flesh out the answer from Eric Koleda a bit more, I ended up solving this two ways, depending on how I was getting the data for the Sheet:

**First**, if I was appending cells to the sheet, I used a function:

```
def set_cell_type(cell_contents):
    current_cell_contents=str(cell_contents).replace(',', '')
    float_cell=re.compile("^\d+\.\d+$")
    int_cell=re.compile("^\d+$")

    if int_cell.search(current_cell_contents):
        data = {"userEnteredValue": {"numberValue": int(current_cell_contents)}}
    elif float_cell.search(current_cell_contents):      
        data =  {"userEnteredValue": {"numberValue": float(current_cell_contents)}}
    else:
        data =  {"userEnteredValue": {"stringValue": str(cell_contents)}}

    return data
```

To format the cells properly.  Here's the call that actually did the appending:

```
rows = [{"values": [set_cell_type(cell) for cell in row]} for row in daily_data_output]
data = { "requests": [ { "appendCells": { "sheetId": all_sheets['Daily record'], "rows": rows, "fields": "*", } } ], }
sheets_batch_update(SHEET_ID,data)
```

**Second**, if I was replacing a whole sheet, I did:

```
#convert the ints to ints and floats to floats
float_cell=re.compile("^\d+\.\d+$")
int_cell=re.compile("^\d+$")
row_list=error_message.split("\t")
i=0
while i < len(row_list):
    current_cell=row_list[i].replace(',', '') #remove the commas from any numbers
    if int_cell.search(current_cell):
        row_list[i]=int(current_cell)
    elif float_cell.search(current_cell):       
        row_list[i]=float(current_cell)
    i+=1
error_output.append(row_list)
```

then the following to actually save error_output to the sheet:

```
data = {'values': [row for row in error_output]}
sheets_update(SHEET_ID,data,'Errors!A1')
```

those two techniques, coupled with the formatting calls I had already figured out in my initial question, did the trick.