# Google Sheet API V4 Date format cell PHP JSON

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

I am creating a google sheet and need to set a cell with date format. I am using a reference from [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#AddConditionalFormatRuleRequest)

My code is as below:

```
$format_requests = array();

$format_requests[] = array(
    'addConditionalFormatRule' => array(
        'rule' => array(
            'ranges' => array(array(
                "sheetId" => 0,
                "startRowIndex" => 0,
                "startColumnIndex" => 1,
                "endColumnIndex" => 1
            )),
            "booleanRule" => array(
                // "condition" => array(
                // )
                "format" => array(
                    "numberFormat" => array(
                        "type" => "DATE",
                        "pattern" => "dddd, mmmm d yyyy"
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);


$format = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest(array('requests' => $format_requests));
$format_result = $service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($spreadsheetId, $format);
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Invalid requests[0].addConditionalFormatRule: ConditionalFormatRule.format only supports bold, italic, strikethrough, foreground color and background color.
```

Comment: Why are you setting this as a conditional format? Set the number format of the cell directly... https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting column in Google Sheets API (with Python) to be number-formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162648/setting-column-in-google-sheets-api-with-python-to-be-number-formatted)